# Proving a sum is divergent under certain conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_k,b_k\}$ are sequences that satisfy:

i) $\sum_k a_k=\infty,\,a_k \to 0$.

ii) $\sup_k b_k \to \infty$ and $b_k$ is bounded from below. Also, $|b_{k+1} -b_{k}| <C$ for some $C>0$.

I have been trying to prove (or disprove) that $\sum_k a_k b_k = \infty.$ My rough line of reasoning is that : Since $\sum_k a_k=\infty$, we have for a given $\epsilon$, $\exists\,m$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^{n+m} a_k >\epsilon$. Then,
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n+m} a_kb_k > \big(\sum_{k=n}^{n+m} a_k\big) \{\sup_{k\in [n,n+m]} b_k -mC  \} 
$$
Since $b_k \to \infty$ along a subsequence, I think we can make sure the difference term in the curly brackets stays positive. I have been trying to formalize the argument but have not been able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it is not true that $\sum_k a_kb_k=\infty$. To obtain a counterexample, consider $a_k=1/k$. Now $b_k$ will spend most of its time at $b_k=-1$, interspersed with intervals where it climbs up to a new peak and returns to $-1$ for a very long time. Since the conditions don't impose any bound on how long $b_k$ can stay at $-1$ before increasing again to the next peak, by making it wait long enough we can even arrange for $\sum_k a_kb_k=-\infty$ (or any value in between).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.